# Docker compose exec into container while using profiles

Tags: bash, docker, docker-compose, devops, exec

Docker-compose introduced the `--profile` [flag](https://docs.docker.com/compose/profiles/) and I am testing it out. Realized that running `docker-compose --profile testprofile exec -it app /bin/sh` doesn't work.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

PS. Running `docker exec -it container_id` works.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to use the v2 command: `docker compose` without a hyphen. Guessing since profiles is a more recent feature.